# RabbitMQ Cannot allocate executable memory. Use the interpreter instead

Tags: rabbitmq, fedora

I have installed rabbitmq on Fedora 35 using yum install rabbitmq-server. I did not touch any configurations. Just run the command `sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server` . Output:

```
    Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered causing the control process to dump core.

    See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xeu rabbitmq-server.service" for details.
```

Also run: `sudo systemctl status rabbitmq-server`. Output:

```
Dec 16 08:18:07 fedora35.linuxvmimages.local systemd[1]: Starting RabbitMQ broker...

Dec 16 08:18:07 fedora35.linuxvmimages.local rabbitmq-server[4953]: beam/jit/x86/beam_asm.cpp:167:pick_allocator(): Internal error: jit: Cannot allocate executable memory. Use the interpreter instead.

Dec 16 08:18:07 fedora35.linuxvmimages.local systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT

Dec 16 08:18:07 fedora35.linuxvmimages.local systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.

Dec 16 08:18:07 fedora35.linuxvmimages.local systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also seeing maybe the same issue when upgrading from Fedora 34 to 35. Definitely a core dump. Steps that resolved it for me was to use the "Zero Dependency" options documented here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html

Basically:

- Remove originals: `sudo dnf remove 'erlang*' rabbitmq-server`
- Install this Erlang, "Zero-dependency Erlang RPM for RabbitMQ": https://github.com/rabbitmq/erlang-rpm
- Add repo: `sudo cat >/etc/yum.repos.d/rabbitmq.repo # ... contents of zero-dep repo`
- Install minimal packages: `sudo dnf install --repo rabbitmq_erlang --repo rabbitmq_server erlang rabbitmq-server`

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the same issue myself, and have seen it in past versions.

I'd recommend using the official Team RabbitMQ packages through an additional set of repositories as they work and are more up to date:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html

Then remove your existing erlang and rabbitmq packages and install with fedora updates package disabled.

```
sudo dnf remove erlang* rabbitmq-server
sudo dnf install rabbitmq-server erlang --disablerepo updates
```

You may also want to make the exclusion permanent for fedora-updates repo by adding:

```
exclude=rabbitmq_server erlang*
```

to your /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo [updates] section.